Does the pressure recovery on an airfoil cause separation more with turbulent BL’s?
If you have a turbulent boundary layer going through pressure recovery on an airfoil, why is it more likely to separate than a laminar boundary layer?
From my research/intuition I think turbulent boundary layers are less likely to separate because they have more mixing of flow.
What sparked this question is in this answer, it talks about “boundary layer tripping” and I found here that means where you make flow turbulent on purpose. Also in that answer it talked about how tripping the boundary layer made separation happen easy.
So basically it said that tripping the BL will cause separation to happen easier because of the pressure recovery not being handled as well and I’m wondering why a turbulent BL wouldn’t handle pressure recovery as well as a laminar BL.

You have this backwards.  A turbulent boundary layer is more likely to stay attached.
The second article you link to indicates that turbulent BL's resist separation (correct).
The first article you link is dealing with a very specific case of a laminar airfoil -- some laminar airfoils have different behavior that is more complex than just the boundary layer's ability to penetrate an adverse pressure gradient.
The intentional boundary layer tripping in the second article is not usually applied to flight vehicles.  It is usually applied to wind tunnel models where you want to simulate the full-scale turbulent behavior, but your model scale would naturally result in laminar flow.
Edit:
An example pressure distribution for a laminar flow airfoil is provided below.

The 'Laminar Rooftop' is a region of the pressure distribution where  there is an extended proverse (sloped up) or neutral (flat) pressure gradient.  This is different from conventional airfoils that typically have a distinct pressure peak near the leading edge and an adverse (sloped down) gradient for the remainder.
Laminar flow can have separation bubbles -- where flow separates from some forward part of the airfoil and then re-attaches slightly later.
Turbulent flow typically separates from the trailing edge first -- as angle of attack is increased, the separation point moves forward.
Consequently, typical turbulent separation is gentle -- at first just a small amount of your airfoil has separated flow.  This increases gradually as you increase alpha.  This results in a $C_L$ vs. $\alpha$ stall curve that is gentle and continues to produce a good amount of lift over a large range.
Conversely, some laminar flow airfoils have much more abrupt separation.  They hold their lift for a good while -- but then they just let go and abruptly lose everything -- because they stall from the leading edge first).


Ah okay, thanks. So how might a laminar airfoil have more complex behavior than a normal one? Aren't laminar airfoils just airfoils that try to avoid strong pressure gradients?

After doing some more research, I found this answer in which it talks about this subject. So from what I read from that, laminar airfoils will be more susceptible to separation because they're laminar, and you need to transition the flow to turbulent for it to stay attached. Is this (at least part) of what is meant by different behavior?
